# Update innerHTML by an email

Tags: javascript, html, email

I don't know if this is possible so I'm very open to trying other methods to achieve similar results.
Basically I have a website and a certain div

```
<div id="mainContent">Content here...</div>
```

What I want to do with this, is be able to send an **email** to a certain address or something similar and the body of the email will define the **"innerHTML"** of this div.
I can imagine it would look something like this in Javascript:

```
document.getElementbyId("mainConetent").innerHTML = emailBody;
```

With obviously "emailBody" being a pre-defined variable.
I am almost certain nothing like this could work but is there any way to achieve a similar thing?

I also know that 'innerHTML' in javascript becomes restored when a page is refreshed. I would like it to be there permenantly on the original document, until a new email is recieved with the new content. This method with javascript is probably not the way to do is. I just used it to explain bettter

Comment: What do you mean? Is `emailBody` the preview of the email that is being send?

Comment: you could try placing the contents of the `email` body in a `input hidden field` and then use this value in place pf the `emailBody`.

Comment: @putvande yes 'emailBody' would be the content of the body of the email sent to a certain email address

Comment: So shouldn't it be the other way around? `emailBody = document.getElementbyId("mainConetent").innerHTML`?

Comment: Look up php's imap_open - you could set up a CRON job to scan the inbox. imap_opn will need the username and password of the mailbox you want to read.

Comment: he actually needs the content of the email body to replace the content of the div.rite mate..??

Comment: Just because you could does not mean you should. Don't do this...if only because of the **serious** security issues.

Comment: @WindsorAndy that looks like it will be able to do the job, but how would I take that information and replace the HTML with?

Comment: is the contents of the `innerhtml` static or database bound..???

Comment: You can run the CRON job at regular intervals and store the results in a database and use an AJAX function to collect those results or have the AJAX call trigger the email scan.

Comment: @Outlooker because I am not quite sure exactly what 'innerHTML' should be (I only used it as an example method - which I don't think would work ) I would probably say that it should be database bound.

Answer (score 0):

Store email body in input `hidden` field and then using javascript you can retrieve them based on `id` and store them in respective `div`.Try this:

**html:**

```
<div id="mainContent">Content here...</div>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $inputbody;?>" id="emailbody">
```

**javascript:**

```
var emailBody = document.getElementbyId("emailbody").value;
document.getElementbyId("mainContent").innerHTML = emailBody;
```

Updated Example:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$inputbody = "Hello! This is a simple email message."; // insert this into hidden field
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

?>
```

Comment: This would be exactly what I need, I am however very unfamiliar with .php . Would you be able to provide help with how to make the php variable 'inputbody' actually equal to the body of the latest email?

Comment: The body of the email that you retrieve from php store it in a variable called `$inputbody` then follow my code..

Comment: What I need to know is how to **retrieve** it within php

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php file add the following piece of code for database connection

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table_name Where type='mail'"));
```

//Inside your `mainContent` div

```
<div id="mainContent"><?php echo $result['innerhtml'] ?></div>
```

?>

In your `js` file

If your email is being sent on button click perform this

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
   emailBody = document.getElementbyId("mainConetent").innerHTML;


    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "update_mail content.php", 
                      data: "emailBody="+ emailBody, 
                      success: function(){

                      }

                  });

})
```

//Updates the content in the databse table usinganother php file named `update_mail content.php` .This flow might help u mate.. :)